# How to disable code formatting in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

IPython has this new feature that reformats my prompt. Unfortunately, it is really buggy, so I want to disable it. I managed to do it when starting IPython from the command line by adding the following line in my `ipython_config.py`:

```py
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoformatter = None
```

However, it does not work when I run it from a python script. I start IPython from my script the following way:

```py
c = traitlets.config.get_config()
c.InteractiveShellEmbed.colors = "Linux"
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoformatter = None
c.InteractiveShellEmbed.loop_runner = lambda coro: loop.run_until_complete(coro)
IPython.embed(display_banner='', using='asyncio', config=c)
```

If I change the `colors` value, the colors change accordingly, so the configuration itself works. However, no matter what I do with `autoformatter`, IPython autoformats my code regardless. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is:

```py
c.InteractiveShellEmbed.autoformatter = None
```